# How to avoid to make an app not in the background running list

Tags: ios4

Is it possible to make the app not enter into the background running app list.

Answer (score 0):

check out adding UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to your apps pList

[UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend anything else I'm missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388951/uiapplicationexitsonsuspend-anything-else-im-missing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend
```

to your .plist file.

This will terminate your app when the home button is pressed, instead of sending it to the background. 
In other words, next time you'll hit the app icon then, the app will relaunch, instead of resuming from where it was when you left.

Here's a screenshot of my .plist:

[image]