# How to exit an IOS application when License Agreement is not accepted by user?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I am aware apple won't support exiting an application programmatically, But I want to exit my application if the user not agreed to the license agreement? Is it possible to restrict the application loading if declined? or What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not crash or force close or find ways to close your application. If user's doesn't accept the agreement then they might not be interested in using your application eventually they will delete it. BUT, do as the protocols say, Display an agreement alert (if you already have an EULA) then point towards the same and ask user that they will have to accept the agreement in order to use the application.

Other ways could be, give a preview of some of the screens (for those who doesn't accept the EULA), if they like your screens then ask for agreement acceptance.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you just keep re-showing the license agreement. If they pick "No", have a popup saying "You must accept the agreement to use this application", and when they tap "OK" re-direct them to the agreement confirmation again.

Answer (score 2):

In one of my app what i did was i have shown the agreement to the user and have asked him to accept or decline it.

If the user declines the agreement then i have shown a pop up informing the user that he cannot proceed further in the app if he declines the agreement and i have kept him on the agreement screen only.

Manually if you exit the application then your app will be rejected by apple because apple does not want an app to function in that manner.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can show a separate view apologizing that without the user giving consent, they will not be able to use your app. That's another opportunity to have them change their mind, by the way.

Comment: But what should I do after that? keep my application running will not look good right?

Comment: They would push the home button faster than you think. Or accept your terms of service.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `NSAssert(NO, @"The user failed to accept the EULA");` would work, perhaps within a delegate callback after presenting an alert view indicating that the application will now exit due to their declining to accept the terms. Then you could easily track the assertion failure in crash reports to determine how many people were rejecting the EULA.

I couldn't say if this will make it past app store review though.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not recommend using `exit(0)`, but I believe it should be OK in your case, since the app should not work if the user did not accept *the license agreement*

But using it to exit a regular app operation is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a notice to the user, and then launch them to your website or facebook page.  This will provide a break in flow as opposed to a dialog that will just appear and disappear until the user feels coerced into clicking "I Agree".

You can also set UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend to YES in your plist which will terminate the app one it goes into the background.  Then you will get a full relaunch when the user comes back into the app from your website.  Information on how to do this is here: [UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend anything else I'm missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388951/uiapplicationexitsonsuspend-anything-else-im-missing)

Answer (score -1):

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication]performSelector:@selector(suspend)];
```

But exiting app like this is not a good practice.

Comment: What is the `suspend` method? Note that you can't call a private API if the app is headed for the app store.